# asp.net: gray out a textbox with enabled = false, but need to get the value

Tags: asp.net, textbox, readonly

I want to disable a textbox for a user.

But in the textbox is a value, that I need to read.

So I want the `readOnly` property (because I can read the value), but also want to gray out the box (function of `enabled = false`), that the user can see, he hasn't access to edit the textbox.

Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Keith setting `Readonly` attribute to input box will be good. You can gray out the text box by changing its background color.

Answer (score 8):

if your text box is a html input text so do this:

```
    <input id="Text1" type="text" value="read me"  readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" />
```

and if it's an asp TextBox then:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  ReadOnly ="true" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Label instead, why you are using TextBox if you want to open edit for user, also change the color of the Label control.